# Indra Sukta - Which Mandala and Hymn

Tags: indra, reference-request

I was wondering if some one could point the Mandala and the Hymn number for the following Suktam:

[Prayer to Indra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyALDYdWW98)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTuoOXEa4SU&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Check this page too: http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1731&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Comment: @Rickross which Mandala and Sukta is the second video from?

Comment: I have not check those mantras so I can not tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YouTube clip is not one single hymn (suktam) from Ṛg Veda Samhitā. It contains a mix of parts of individual mantras from Ṛg Veda Samhitā and Yajur Veda.

The YouTube clip is not accurately titled. Not all the mantras are addressed to Indra. There are mantras addressed to Agni, Indrāgnī, Agnīṣomau, Ṛtavah (seasons) and Chandāmsi (meters).

However, the style of recitation is completely Yajur Veda. So it's more appropriate to say that these mantras are taken from Yajur Veda. That's not surprising because Yajur Veda also contains many mantras of Ṛg Veda.

As far as I can discern, here are the individual mantras:

1. Yajur Veda Taittīriya Samhitā 2.2.8.3 (Deity: Indra, description of ritual):

> (सङ्ग्राममेतामेव निर्वपेद्)यो हतमनाः स्वयंपाप इव स्यादेतानि हि वा एतस्मादपक्रान्तान्यथैष हतमनाः स्वयंपाप इन्द्रमेव मन्युमन्तं मनस्वन्तँ् स्वेन भागधेयेनोप धावति स एवास्मिन्निन्द्रियं मन्युं मनो दधाति न हतमनाः स्वयंपापो भवति......॥३॥

2. RV 2.12.1 (Deity: Indra):

> यो जात एव प्रथमो मनस्वान्देवो देवान्क्रतुना पर्यभूषत् ।
> यस्य शुष्माद्रोदसी अभ्यसेतां नृम्णस्य मह्ना स जनास इन्द्रः ॥

3. RV 7.25.1 (Deity: Indra):

> आ ते मह इन्द्रोत्युग्र समन्यवो यत्समरन्त सेनाः । पताति दिद्युन्नर्यस्य बाह्वोर्मा ते मनो विष्वद्र्य१ग्वि चारीत् ॥

4. Yajur Veda Taittīriya Samhitā 1.5.5.3-4 (Deity: Agni):

> आयुर्दा अग्नेऽस्यायुर्मे ॥३॥ देहि वर्चोदा अग्नेऽसि वर्चो मे देहि तनूपा अग्नेऽसि तनुवं मे पाह्यग्ने यन्मे तनुवा ऊनं तन्म आ पृण चित्रावसो स्वस्ति ते पारमशीयेन्धानास्त्वा शतँ् हिमा द्युमन्तः समिधीमहि वयस्वन्तो वयस्कृतं यशस्वन्तो यशस्कृतँ् सुवीरासो अदाभ्यम् । अग्ने सपत्नदम्भनं वर्षिष्ठे अधि नाके । सं त्वमग्ने सूर्यस्य वर्चसाऽगथाः समृषीणाँ् स्तुतेन सं प्रियेण धाम्ना । त्वमग्ने सूर्यवर्चा असि सं मामायुषा वर्चसा प्रजया सृज ॥४॥

5. Yajur Veda Taittīriya Samhitā 1.6.2.2-4 (Deities: Manas, Agni, Indra, Agnīṣomau, Indrāgnī, Ṛtavah-Seasons):

> मनोऽसि प्राजापत्यं मनसा मा भूतेनाऽऽ विश वागस्यैन्द्री सपत्नक्षयणी ॥२॥ वाचा मेन्द्रियेणाऽऽ विश वसन्तमृतूनां प्रीणामि स मा प्रीतः प्रीणातु ग्रीष्ममृतूनां प्रीणामि स मा प्रीतः प्रीणातु वर्षा ऋतूनां प्रीणामि ता मा प्रीताः प्रीणन्तु शरदमृतूनां प्रीणामि सा मा प्रीता प्रीणातु हेमन्तशिशिरावृतूनां प्रीणामि तौ मा प्रीतौ प्रीणीतामग्नीषोमयोरहं देवयज्यया चक्षुष्मान् भूयासमग्नेरहं देवयज्ययाऽन्नादो भूयासम् ॥३॥ दब्धिरस्यदब्धौ भूयासममुं दभेयमग्नीषोमयोरहं देवयज्यया वृत्रहा भूयासमिन्द्राग्नियोरहं देवयज्ययेन्द्रियाव्यन्नादो भूयासमिन्द्रस्याहं देवयज्ययेन्द्रियावी भूयासं महेन्द्रस्याहं देवयज्यया जेमानं महिमानं गमेयमग्नेः स्विष्टकृतोऽहं देवयज्ययाऽऽयुष्मान्यज्ञेन प्रतिष्ठां गमेयम् ॥४॥

6. Yajur Veda Taittīriya Samhitā 2.2.5.3-4 (Deities: Vaiśvānara Agni, Chandāmsi-Meters, description of ritual):

> वैश्वानरं द्वादशकपालं निर्वपेत्पुत्रे जाते यदष्टाकपालो भवति गायत्रियैवैनं ब्रह्मवर्चसेन पुनाति यन्नवकपालस्त्रिवृतैवास्मिन्तेजो दधाति यद्दशकपालो विराजैवास्मिन्नन्नाद्यं दधाति यदेकादशकपालस्त्रिष्टुभैवास्मिन्निन्द्रियं दधाति यद्द्वादशकपालो जगत्यैवास्मिन्पशून्दधाति यस्मिञ्जात एतामिष्टिं निर्वपति पूतः ॥३॥ एव तेजस्व्यन्नाद इन्द्रियावी पशुमान्भवति.........॥४॥

Answer (score 2):

The link on the youtube you are referring seems to be from some source but that is not Indra Suktha. The various versions are:

However,
[Indra Suktha](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/r01.html) is traditionally is chanted from

rigveda samhitaa, manDala 1, suktam 32

rushih hiranyastoopa aangirasa, Chanda trishTup, devataa indra

Source: [Vedic secrets](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/vedic-secrets-in-compact-form-set-of-2-volumes-NAK527/) by T.V.Kapali Sastri and later edited by R. L. Kashyap.

This is also confirmed by [this site](https://godsglitz.com/indra-suktam/) and [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/gurukulam4vedas/vedic-archives/udaka%20shanti%20-sanskrit.pdf?attredirects=0&d=1)

The [chanting of this version](https://youtu.be/V_5LMumH4D0) can also be found in youtube.

[Another version of Indra suktam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaVZbtqloDA) based on Rig veda 2.12 can also be found in youtube.

Another version of [Indra suktam based on Rig veda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTuoOXEa4SU&feature=emb_logo) 1.4 is also available.

However, this [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7Q5cFguIUmqECdsWyPqYYw), has named everything such as 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7 as Indra sukta. This is incorrect.

Comment: Did you checked it with sukta given by OP. I don't think that it's 1.32. The starting isn't matching.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my answer appropriately. Please check.

Comment: It seems like Mandala 1 Sukta 4 is: https://www.aurobindo.ru/workings/matherials/rigveda/01/01-004.htm does not seem to match?

Comment: I am sorry. Can you please type the first few lines of the chanted verse? Then we can check it against sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/r01.html or from the second chapter. It does not match 2.12 also. It must be one of the verses. My speakers are not working now.